# How to implement an interface like this in Android application?

Tags: android

good afternoon

How could I get a design like this in my android application?

http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/previo/thump_7851660img20120718wa0000.jpg

That is, divided into three areas with different background color to the background activity. And for example in the first zone instead of having these options has a TextView and edit text where you enter something.

How to make something like that image what kind of layout is more recomedable use? Linear, Relative ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a fragment layout and use fragments to get that layout

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `PreferenceScreen` with three `PreferenceSection`s.